# Number of flags a user received is unreadable on Programmers.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Not sure if this is specific to Programmers.SE or if it appears on other sites as well. As a moderator on Programmers.SE, I'm looking at the profile of a user who received a few flags. The flag count is unreadable until after I click on it to view the page.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Neh, not specific to Programmers, actually. Saw it on Gaming, it seems like it's just the same thing they did with the Suggested Edits when those first came out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.