# Should we edit old posts and change Programmers to Software Engineering?

Tags: discussion, edits, site-name

The Stack Exchange site that was known for years as Programmers.SE has been officially renamed to Software Engineering a while ago. Obviously, in any new post we should use the new name.

However, should we also edit old posts to reflect the change? [Here is one example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84264/number-of-flags-a-user-received-is-unreadable-on-programmers-se), where someone edited then someone else rolled back the edit:

> [image]

So, before we go into edit wars, can we please reach a decision here and act (or not act) upon it?

Comment: Maybe you want to add a reference to [this query result](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=programmers.se+duplicate%3A0+closed%3A0) ... only 147 hits for now. And [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/170896/revisions) is another example of a similar edit ... from ... euh ... oeps! Apart from that: I take the 5th.

Answer (score 9):

There is no reason not to, *but only when it **actually** helps*. The questions need to be considered carefully, first. For example:

- 7 year old questions with 30 views do not necessarily need to be bumped to the home page for this. While the edit may seem philosophically correct, it is not useful. Nobody will benefit from these types of questions, nothing is improved in reality, and the home page ends up cluttered with old bumps.
- The vast majority of these questions can actually probably be closed at this point, e.g. as pertaining to a specific site, or sometimes even no-repro.

So if you *are* going to make an edit, instead of blindly editing, it's important to actually read the question and consider what the appropriate action should be. Don't edit it if it's not a useful question. Close it (without editing and bumping) if it needs to be closed. Etc. Before editing ask yourself "Who will benefit from this change?".

This applies not just to editors, but to reviewers of suggested edits as well. Always be sure to take a good look at the question and make sure the suggested edit *matters* and/or consider if there is a more appropriate action to be taken (such as closure).

This goes for all such "edit quests" in general, by the way. Not just programmers -> software engineering.

As for rolling back: To me, the major issue is the bumps, and a rollback doesn't help with that. The other issue is when a more appropriate action should've been taken, which you can still take without a rollback. If the edit is already made, unless it hurts the question itself, might as well leave it alone at that point. If somebody else does choose to roll it back, personally I'd just let it go, because if it's on an inconsequential question, then at the end of the day it doesn't *really* matter if it's "programmers" or "softwareengineering", and what's done is done (edits, rollbacks, and all), no reason to carry it on or start edit wars on old posts. The one case where you'd want to roll it back, though, is if the literal name "programmers" itself is critical to the question, although I can't think of an example.

Also, please excuse me for not being completely articulate, I haven't had any coffee yet.

Comment: And suppose edit was already made, is there any point rolling it back?

Comment: @ShadowWizard IMHO not really. To me, the major issue is the bumps and a rollback doesn't help with that. If the edit is already made, might as well leave it alone. If somebody else does choose to roll it back, personally I'd just let it go. If it's on an inconsequential question, then at the end of the day it doesn't *really* matter if it's "programmers" or "softwareengineering", and what's done is done, no reason to carry it on. The one case where you'd want to roll it back, though, is if the literal name "programmers" itself is critical to the question, although I can't think of an example.

Comment: Example: [this six-year-old bug report (now fixed) that turned out not to be site-specific](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84264/162102), did *not* need to be bumped today.